# Setting int column to NULL sets value but then reverts

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a table with a column, UnitStatus defined as an **int** with Allow Nulls. If I run something like this:

```
UPDATE TheTable SET UnitStatus = NULL WHERE blah blah
```

and then follow immediately with a SELECT ... I see NULL for the column value(s). If I run the SELECT query again the values are all back to 1, which is what they were before the update.

There are no constraints or triggers that reference this field; any idea how I determine what is happening?

Here is more detail, and I'm doing this from SSMS:

```
BEGIN TRAN T1
  UPDATE TrackedUnits SET [UnitStatus] = NULL WHERE UnitID = 92
COMMIT TRAN T1

SELECT UnitID, UnitStatus FROM TrackedUnits WHERE UnitID = 92
```

If I execute this from SSMS the results show UnitStatus as NULL. If I immediately run just the SELECT again, all the values are back to 1.

From SSMS I see there is one trigger on the table to prevent row deletion and no constraints except on a couple text (nvarchar) fields not shown above.

I also ran a query to find triggers and constraints on the table just in case something could be hidden, not sure how, but just to be safe ... didn't find anything. Also account I'm using is dbadmin so nothing should be hidden.

Probably will be something simple, but I can't find the *needle* that's poking.

Thanks

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in a dbfiddle? Have you any trigger or events that set the vaöues back

Comment: Well DaleK you have high reputation on sql-server answers by this is hard to think you had ignored important details, but as long as I known the behavior you describe for me matches with a rollback scenario (are all after-queries made on the same connection session?). If you have permissions on DB ¿Had you tried recording rows modifications through a trigger just to get evidence if there is another login/application/ip restoring the values?

Comment: @MauricioOrtega not my question, I just edited it

Comment: Are you using Python and `autocommit=false` maybe?

Comment: @DaleK you asked `"¿how I determine what is happening?"` First, you must consider all details to set the scenario: 1) Observe `@@TRANCOUNT` value before  to execute the UPDATE 2) Be sure you execute the `UPDATE` and the two `SELECT` on the same database  session/connection to check this you can add `@@TRANCOUNT, as Trancount, @@SPID as SPID` to your queries to verify they are equals. 3) ¿Do you checked if there are no jobs that revert that column? 4) I suggested to create a trigger to record `@@SPID, APP_NAME(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), HOST_NAME()` as a way to `"determine what is happening"`

Comment: @MauricioOrtega This question is asked by Rick, I don't know why are you commenting to DaleK !

Comment: @DaleK I got confused. Excuse me for the comments.

Comment: @Rick you mentioned you use dbadmin login. Create a table and a trigger to record changes on the column, I think this way can give you more evidence to track the error. I can't put the code on a comment, neither on the answer because (by itself) I can't verify if that answer your question. Let's create a chat for your quiestion.

Comment: Thanks @MauricioOrtega, turns out it was simple, code running in an application that resets the value if null. In production there are 10, 20 , 30+ client connections for this particular assembly line any of which can "make the correction". After setting up in DEV system I was able to set the pace and the problem jumped right out.